# Opencv No module named cv2 on Windows 10

Tags: python

I was making a hand tracking script and when i first test it i get and error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Code Stuff\Python\Hand Track\trackhand.py", line 1, in <module>
      import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

The thing is I have opencv-python, numpy installed. What should i do

Python 3.10

Comment: try `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: How did you install them? Are you using Fonda environments or any other flavor of virtual environments? Which python executable are you using?

Comment: I'm using pip and I have tried `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: How about `import cv`?

Comment: maybe you have to two Pythons installed and you installed module in one Python but you run code with other Python. Pythons don't share modules. In console/terminal check versions `python -V` and `pip -V`. If you run code with `python script.py` then you could use the same python  to install all modules `python -m pip install ....`

Comment: don't think cv will help and no I do not have 2 pythons installed